# Firebase BigQuery export - Historical data

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

When I try to search for historical data for events on BigQuery I can only find events from the last week. I couldn't find anywhere the information if this is correct, or if I am doing something wrong. Basically it seems that I can only query events_YYYYMMDD from the past week. Is this correct?

Comment: It entirely depends on your data - do you have an expiry on your dataset? It is possible to set this to 7 days, so you would never have data older than 7 days available, but is it not a default setting.

Answer (score 2):

Did you by any chance enable the BigQuery export from Firebase a week ago?

Keep in mind: Firebase will only write to BigQuery that it receives from the moment you enable the integration. It won't write historical data.

Comment: Hi Frank, Is your answer still valid, I ask this because the statement [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export) confused me. *"Firebase exports a copy of your existing data to BigQuery export."* By the way, my question is for Firebase Crashlytics, in case analytics and crashlytics exporting behaviours are different.

Comment: The "a copy of" in there means that Firebase doesn't use BigQuery as its own datastore, but instead exports the data from Firebase to BigQuery for your use. I don't know whether Crashlytics exports historical data, but from a quick scan of the docs it seems to follow the same logic as Analytics.